# How to delete a file from storage using file's path?

Tags: java, filepath, delete-file, internal-storage

I am working on an app that list all the audio files from shared internal storage and removable SD card.
Now if the user wants to delete a particular file , it will be deleted from shared internal storage or removable SD card.

The issue I am facing is file.delete does not work , I have used mediastore to get all audio files.

These were the audio file paths i got from media store.

This is from internal shared storage.

```
/storage/emulated/0/Music/Guitar1.mp3
```

This is from removable micro SD card.

```
/storage/BBF8-A8D3/Guitar1.mp3
```

After getting these paths

```
  File deleteFile = new File(s.getFilepath());
  boolean delete = deleteFile.delete();
```

The delete gives `false` as delete file is not deleted.

Now I have tried this,

```
    File deleteFile = new File(s.getFilepath());
    if(deleteFile.exists()) {
    boolean catchdelete = deleteFile.delete();}
```

Now after creating file from path , if condition fails as delete File does not exist.

So why newly created file does not exist(file is not a directory) does it require file input stream.

My main issue is to delete a file from storage through the app.

This is my method for retreiving audio file paths

```
public ArrayList<String> getAudiosPath(Activity activity, Context context) {
            //  Uri uri;
            listOfAllAudios = new ArrayList<String>();
            Cursor cursor;

            final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID};
            final String orderBy = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID;
            //Stores all the audio from the gallery in Cursor
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
                    null, orderBy);
            //Total number of audios
            int count = cursor.getCount();

            //Create an array to store path to all the audios
            String[] arrPath = new String[count];

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(i);
                int dataColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

                //Store the path of the audio
                arrPath[i] = cursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
                Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.headphone512, null)).getBitmap();

                bitmap.add(b);
                Log.i("PATH", arrPath[i]);
                listOfAllAudios.add(arrPath[i]);
            }

            //  count_paths=listOfAllAudios.size();

            return listOfAllAudios;
        }
```

Now i have applied Apache Commons IO File Utils

```
 File deleteFile = new File(s.getFilepath());
     // boolean delete = deleteFile.delete();
      try {
          FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.getFile(s.getFilepath()));
        } 
    catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This Apache Commons file utils does delete the file but issue is when opening the app again i am seeing the file path with file size 0 KB.

In Download Nav drawer

[image: Nav drawer]

when in Nav drawer i access  TA-1032-> Music -> Empty(No File present)
  (there is no file which means file gets deleted)

But in Nav drawer i access Audio-> Unknown -> Music -> Guitar.mp3 (file present but file size is 0 and cant be played)

so this is some how getting the path of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Apache Commons as a dependency and use their file API for the operation.

```
FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.getFile(s.getFilepath()));
```

Comment: i tried  usiing FileUtils with try catch and it says File Not found exception. Although the path that i am recieving  is from file.getAbsolutepath(); which gives correct path from storage.

Answer (score 1):

This piece might work.

```
Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Mayank\\Desktop\\ 
        445.mp3"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Code snip will be helpful

```
File directory = new File("c:\\directoryname\\filename.txt");-- give your path where file is located.

        try {

            FileUtils.forceDelete(directory);

            System.out.println("force delete file in java");

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me , the code posted by @dammina deleted the file but still was accessible from media store so the other method will take care of it.

```
     File deleteFile = new File(s.getFilepaths());

   try {                                               
      FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.getFile(s.getFilepaths()));                                             
       //   adapterRecycler.notifyDataChanged();                                              
         adapterRecycler.notifyDataChanged(sectionHeaders);
                                            }
         catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }


 deleteFileFromMediaStore(getContentResolver(), deleteFile);
```

method for deleting from media store because even after deleting file it is still accessible through media store.

```
public static int deleteFileFromMediaStore(final ContentResolver contentResolver, final File file) {
            String canonicalPath;
            try {
                canonicalPath = file.getCanonicalPath();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                canonicalPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            }
           // MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA
            final Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
            final int result = contentResolver.delete(uri,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + "=?", new String[]{canonicalPath});
            if (result == 0) {
                final String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                if (!absolutePath.equals(canonicalPath)) {
                    int deletedRow = contentResolver.delete(uri,
                            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + "=?", new String[]{absolutePath});
                    return deletedRow;
                }
            } else return result;
            return result;
        }
```